# How to Display Data without a model in Asp.net Mvc?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I m using SqlInjectionQuery with MVC

I Insert, update, delete a record in a Database successfully but I want the Display them. I have No model class

I create a controller

EmptyController:

```
namespace mvccruddatabase.Controllers
{
    public class EmptyController : Controller
    {
         StudentEntities db = new StudentEntities();       

        //static connection  
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Perfect\Documents\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

        SqlCommand cmd;    //fire the query
        SqlDataReader dr;  //Data Read

        //get the data
        public ActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost] //post means post the data
        public ActionResult Add(String empname,int empage) 
        {
            cn.Open();
            //Sql Injection Query
            cmd=new SqlCommand("insert into tblemp(empname,empage) values('"+empname+"','"+empage+"')",cn);
            int validate = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

            if(validate > 0)
            {
                Response.Write("successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Not successfully");
            }
            cn.Close();
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult DisplayData()
        {
            return View(db.tblemps.ToList());
            //return View();
        }
```

```
Add.cshtml

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Add</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <form method="post" action="">
           Name:<input type="text" name="empname"/><br/>
           Age:<input type="text" name="empage" /><br/>
               <input type="submit" value="insert"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display data from database?

I m trying but here how to fetch the database field id

```
DisplayData.cshtml

@model IEnumerable<mvccruddatabase.Models.tblemp>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DisplayData</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Id
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            EmpName
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            EmpAge
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @item.empid
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.empname
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.empage
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        <br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to Display Data from database??

Comment: How would your DisplayData.cshtml know what data to show? You will have to provide a model class from the controller or at the very least put some data in the Viewbag

Comment: P.S. you _can_ use the viewbag to store bits of data and show them on the page, and that occasionally has a purpose, but it's not a substitute for just using MVC as it's intended to be used. IMHO you're just making life hard for yourself by not having a model. It's not a difficult thing to set one up.

Comment: P.P.S. I saw one of your little comments in the code. "Integrated Security" just basically means telling .NET to use your logged-in Windows user details to connect to the database. If you're confused about a piece of terminology it's usually trivial to google it. In this case, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server would be a sensible article to read.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for suggestion solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AdresaRepository
{
    private OracleConnection oracleConnection;

    public AdresaRepository(OracleConnection oracleConnection)
    {
        this.oracleConnection = oracleConnection;
    }

    public string CreateAdr(AdresaModel obAdresa)//
    {
        string result = "";

        try
        {
            string oString = "insert into adresa(id_adresa, strada, nr_str, bloc, localitate_id_loc) values(@id_adresa, @strada, @nr_str, @bloc, @localitate_id_loc)";
            var cmdc = new OracleCommand(oString, oracleConnection);

            cmdc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@id_adresa", obAdresa.IdAdresa));
            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@strada", obAdresa.Strada));
            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@nr_str", obAdresa.NrStrada));
            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@bloc", obAdresa.Bloc));
            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@localitate_id_loc", obAdresa.IdLoc));

            oracleConnection.Open();
            result = cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
            oracleConnection.Close();

            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            return result = "";
        }
        finally
        {
            oracleConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```